# How to auto fill text field in Classic ASP

Tags: autocomplete, asp-classic

I have 5 textboxes (`name`, `roll No`, `address` etc) and I want that when I fill my name in first text box (`name`) then it should fill my all 4 fields automatically which I filled.

I got this in ASP.Net but I want to use this same in classic ASP.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. To populate fields you need to tell us Where is the data coming from .

Comment: Currently your question makes no sense at all. Please edit it with mode details and explain where the data is coming from.

Comment: I want data which is stored in Cache memory. I doesn't want it come from DB.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to fire off an ajax call via a onkeypress javascript function call that calls a script which queries your database and gets data for user when it finds a match.

```
<input type="text" id="uName" name="uName" value="" onkeypress="getUserDetails(this.value)"/>
```

You can then use the data and further ajax to populate the additional fields.